# Apply Cyclic all at once

Tags: animation, timeline

It seems like I can't just select all channels at once in the timeline. How can I apply cyclic to  multiple channels at the same time?

Answer (score 2):

As an experiment, I tried doing this from the Graph Editor using a Cyclic Modifier with more than one channel selected at the same time. Unfortunately, it always favors one of the channels, and it alone gets the cycle modifier added.

However, the functionality you're after could be achieved using action strips in the NLA Editor. Because when you cycle those strips, it cycles everything in the strip, no matter how many keyframed channels it contains.

With the NLA open, and your action selected in the Action Editor (Action Editor is one of several editing contexts accessible from the Dope Sheet), push the strip down, so that it's accessible from the NLA. Next, press <kbd>n</kbd> to roll out the Properties Shelf (make sure you're floating your cursor in the NLA Editor window before doing this), and press the *Strip* tab. You will see that you have access to various ways of controlling the behavior of action strips. One of those is the **Repeat** option, which is under the *Action Strip* section. Here, you can enter a number and then the strip will cycle that many times.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, looks like that works.

I also noticed that you can actually select multiple by selecting bones. You can click drag select the list on the left, but you cannot select all this way. Seems like there should be a select-all option there.